# shell script throwing "No such file or directory" error while command line works perfect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to run a simple piece of shell script which return No such file or directory while executing the statement from command line works perfect.

Any leads ??

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /home/dev/.bashrc
```

I am executing the script like this:

```
bash ~/Desktop/test.sh
```

Comment: which file does not exist? `ls -l ~/Desktop/test.sh /home/dev/.bashrc` -- it's possible you have DOS-style line endings in that script and you are trying to `cat /home/dev/.bashrc^M` -- do: `od -c ~/Desktop/test.sh`

Comment: this is the output of od -c

0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \r  \n   c   a   t
0000020       /   h   o   m   e   /   d   e   v   /   .   b   a   s   h
0000040   r   c  \r  \n
0000044

Comment: converting with dos2unix solved the problem.. I use gedit / intellij for writing shell script can u suggest an editor where I won't be facing this issue ..

Comment: Look for an option or preference to set the file format (Unix or dos) in your favourite editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `\r` at the end of `/bin/bash` so it's trying to run `/bin/bash\r` which does not exist.  Use just `\n` to terminate lines. You can convert existing files with `dos2unix`, or a similar tool if you have it available:

```
dos2unix /home/dev/.bashrc
```

The `\r` in the shebang line isn't actually coming into play yet because you're invoking it as `bash test.sh` so it isn't using it, but it's the same problem

Comment: converting with dos2unix solved the problem.. 
I use gedit / intellij for writing shell script can u suggest an editor where I won't be facing this issue ..

Comment: In vim you can ´:set ff=unix´ to convert files to unix format.